# Antd switch not triggering onValuesChange when toggling?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a basic form:

```
<Form
  layout="vertical"
  form={form}
  onFinish={onSubmit}
  onValuesChange={onValueChanges}
>
  <Form.Item
    label="Foo"
    name="requirePassword"
    valuePropName="checked"
  >
    <Switch />

        {requirePasswordSettingDirty && (
          <span className={styles.requirePasswordWarning}>
            Required password
          </span>
        )}
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

When I click the switch, it doesn't trigger the callback `onValueChanges`. What am I missing?

Comment: because the switch is not an component that is binded with the Form. it has separate event. try checkbox or something.

Comment: It is because the extra element or something, the `<span>`. Removing that fixes it. How can I add the span too? The checkbox has the same problem if I include the `requirePasswordSettingDirty` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data binding is tied to a `Form.Item` with `name` key and wraps only an Input. Therefore if you have additional elements alongside the Input, such as a custom label element, you'll have to nest `Form.Items`.

```
 <Form.Item label="Foo" valuePropName="checked">
    <Form.Item name="requirePassword">
      <Switch />
    </Form.Item>
    {requirePasswordSettingDirty && <span>Required password</span>}
  </Form.Item>
```